# How to inherit impersonation from parent thread to all child threads (WIN32)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, impersonation

I have to do some task in my system service but on behalf of current user, then I referred to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser

**My scenario is:**
1. create thread A: runs in system mode and impersonates to current user mode.
2. create child threads B[N] from thread A.

**Current result:**
threads B[N] are running with system mode

**Expected Result:**
threads B[N] run in USER mode as its parent thread.

Comment: thread impersonation is not inherited. you need direct call `SetThreadToken` on B threads.

Comment: Currently, I'm invoking a function from a third party lib, in that function it spawns a new thread to do its job. Then now I would like to run that function's thread as USER mode (my current thread is in SYSTEM mode), then am I able to do so?

Comment: You can run a process with reduced privilege, and use the library inside that process.  Then the threads the library starts will be limited as well.